# Unable to add more than one function to Test Class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am developing a Web Application using Laravel. I would like to Unit Test some logic. So I created a Unit Test class like below.

```
class AcceptationTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testCountUpWhenDifferenceIsOverOneWeek()
    {
        $acceptationRepo = new AcceptationRepo;
        //must count up on 5/12/2017
        $need_count_up = $acceptationRepo->shouldCountUpTwoDWeek("11-28-2017");
        $this->assertTrue($need_count_up);
    }


}
```

I run the Unit Test from Terminal and it is working. Then I added another test function. So my test class will look like this.

```
class AcceptationTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testCountUpWhenDifferenceIsOverOneWeek()
    {
        $acceptationRepo = new AcceptationRepo;
        //must count up on 5/12/2017
        $need_count_up = $acceptationRepo->shouldCountUpTwoDWeek("11-28-2017");
        $this->assertTrue($need_count_up);
    }

    public function testNotCountUpIfDifferenceIsExactlySeven(){
        $acceptationRepo = new AcceptationRepo;
        //must count up on 5/12/2017
        $need_count_up = $acceptationRepo->shouldCountUpTwoDWeek("11-29-2017");
        $this->assertTrue(!$need_count_up);

    }
}
```

When I run the test from the Terminal, it is showing this error.

[image]

I checked my second function carefully and there is no error. To make sure I removed the first function and run the second function alone. So my test class will look like this.

```
class AcceptationTest extends TestCase
{


    public function testNotCountUpIfDifferenceIsExactlySeven(){
        $acceptationRepo = new AcceptationRepo;
        //must count up on 5/12/2017
        $need_count_up = $acceptationRepo->shouldCountUpTwoDWeek("11-29-2017");
        $this->assertTrue(!$need_count_up);

    }
}
```

As you can see there is only one function in the test class and that is the newly added function. I run the test from the terminal again and now it is working without throwing any error. I found out the problem is adding more than one functions. But I need to do it. I read the error message from the terminal and it is not dealing with the Unit Test at all.

I tried adding these two properties

```
protected $preserveGlobalState = FALSE;
protected $runTestInSeparateProcess = TRUE;
```

When I run, it is giving me this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to remove constants from your code.  You should be able to reference `env` variables or `config` variables in most places where you are using constants.

Other option is to use these flags to ensure each test gets it's own process:

```
class AcceptationTest extends TestCase
{

  protected $preserveGlobalState = FALSE;
  protected $runTestInSeparateProcess = TRUE;
```

Finally, you could add a test to wherever you're defining your constant

```
if (!defined('SITE_NAME')) define('SITE_NAME', 'foobar');
```